# What are the specific setups to avoid perpetual checks(Queen)?

Tags: endgame, queen-endgame, perpetual

I was wondering if there certain setups with pieces, pawns, or both which avoid perpetual checks. I know an important setup is the one below where it's essentially a fortress type of a position for white. Are there any other ways to avoid perpetual checks. The reason I am asking for this is that in endgames I often blunder perpetual.

[image]

Comment: FWIW, you highlighted Bd3 in the diagram, but it is unnecessary. The configuration Ka2-Pa4-b3-c2 is enough by itself to prevent a lone queen perpetual.

Comment: @Evargalo I was thinking in more general terms. In this particular position, you could be right, but in general, the bishop is required to guard the c2 pawn since if it doesn't exist the black queen can attack it forcing some piece to defend it(If the king defends it then the checks are possible through the back rank or the dark square diagonal).

Comment: @Evargalo It prevents perpetual "check", but I have seen positions where this setup, more often on the kingside, leads to a draw because the Pc2 gets attacked by Qc3, for example, and then Kb1, and then Qe1; Kb2 Qd4; Ka2 Qc3, and you start again. It is not all check, but still leads to a repetition.

Comment: trade queens much earlier and avoid the problem

Comment: I used to offer a draw when I was better in every queen ending.  I had no idea what was going on and they ended in a perpetual or a loss when my opponents queen supports their passed pawn.  Then I did a focused study of queen endings and now I enjoy them.  Turns out if my opponent has a passed pawn I probably wasn’t better after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be very helpful if you would post a couple of those games you mentioned that you gave up perpetual check.

I would say, "no", there are no stock positions that are meant to avoid perpetual check (at least I cannot think of any now that I would call "common"). You just have to be careful, and be aware of king safety. Sometimes, you just cannot avoid it either as it is a valid component of defense.

I will say that one common setup in queen endings is the following type of position. White has managed to post the queen very centrally, and it can go either from the h1-a8 diagonal, as it is now, to prevent checks; or as it helps the a-pawn move forward, it can move to the g1-a7 diagonal to defend e3, and help advance the pawn from there. It is critical to note that with rooks on the board, the white king's lack of safety would probably prevent this, keeping a white rook passive on the first, and allow black to setup counterplay against the passer.

```
 [FEN "8/5pk1/q5p1/P2Q3p/7P/6P1/5PK1/8 w - - 0 0"]

 1. Qd4+ Kh7 2. Qb6 {And the passer moves on}
```